# Как записать двумерный вектор короче?

Tags: c++, vector

Каждый раз при создании двумерного вектора приходится писать

```
vector<vector<int>>
```

Это не удобно. Как это можно записать более коротко?

Comment: Написать один раз `using M = vector<vector<int>>;`, и после этого писать `M v;` :) Так устраивает?

Comment: можно и для  вектора с вектором элементами любого типа: template<typename T>
using M = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;  Использовать M<int>, M<float>...

Comment: @Harry да устраивает :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать алиас типа или макрос:

```
using Vec2D = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

Если вектор определяется вместе с инициализирующим выражением, то можно вывести тип автоматически с помощью CTAD или `auto`. В параметре функции -- с помощью шаблонного параметра. В возвращаемом типе функции -- с помощью `auto` или `decltype(auto)`. И тому подобное.

Также часто не нужен вектор векторов, а можно обойтись одним вектором с индексацией `i * column + j` для имитации матрицы.